# Unable to connect to Elasticache serverless memcached from Lambda within same VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, memcached, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to implement AWS Elasticache serverless memcached for Lambda. I have successfully provisioned serverless Elasticache inside VPC spanning two private subnets. I have enabled `dns_hostnames` for VPC as well. I have successfully deployed lambda inside same VPC using same 2 private subnets. I have attached security group allowing `11211` TCP & `11212` TCP inbound traffic to my Elasticache. I'm using `memcache-plus` NPM module inside lambda to connect to Elasticache server. I have even attached `elasticache:*` IAM permission on lambda. The problem is, whenever I invoke my lambda it is failing at this step:

```
const MemcachePlus = require('memcache-plus');
const client = new MemcachePlus({
  hosts: [process.env.ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT],
  autodiscover: true,
  onNetError: function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  },
});
```

**Lambda Security Group:**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_enabled_lambda_sg" {
  name        = "bp-${terraform.workspace}-vpc-lambda-sg"
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.db_proxy_vpc.id

  # To Allow Port 80 Transport
  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    description = "Allow HTTP traffic from within VPC"
  }

  # Open port 8000 for external access
  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 443
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    description = "Allow HTTPS traffic from within VPC"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

**Elasticache Security Group:**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elasticache_memcached_sg" {
  name        = "bp-${terraform.workspace}-elasticache-memcached-sg"
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.db_proxy_vpc.id

  # To Allow Port 11211 Transport
  ingress {
    from_port   = 11211
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 11211
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    description = "Allow memcache traffic from within VPC"
  }

  # Open port 8000 for external access
  ingress {
    from_port   = 11212
    protocol    = "tcp"
    to_port     = 11212
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    description = "Allow memcache read traffic from within VPC"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

What is am I missing here, to successfully connect to Elasticache?

Tried invoking lambda, moving `MemcachePlus` class inside & outside lambda handler.

Comment: Do you have any terraform code?

Comment: Is this CDKTF for Node.js?

Comment: @MarkoE Elasticache, VPC & lambda are configured using terraform.
```
egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```
This is outbound rule for lambda.

Comment: @SreeTeja Do not use screenshots of code, rather reproducible blocks of code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @SreeTeja Also, in this case, I think you might want to allow ingress access from the **Lambda SG** to the Elasticache SG.

Comment: @MarkoE when I tried to add ingress rule allowing **Lambda SG** as source in **Elasticache SG**, I'm getting `sg-xxxxxxxxxxx" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address: sg-xxxxxxxxxxxx` error :(

Comment: @MarkoE **ERROR** `{
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write'
}`

Comment: Well, you either use a CIDR block or an SG ID: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule#source_security_group_id.

Comment: yes, I used `VPC` CIDR block earlier, now tried to use lambda SG ID and got that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256756/discussion-between-sree-teja-and-marko-e).

Comment: @Mark B can u help me resolve this?

Comment: @MarkoE I think serverless Elasticache is TLS based, so thats not able to connect using `memcache-plus`. Is there any other way to do it from lambda?

Comment: I was able to connect from EC2 running `openssl s_client -connect ENDPOINT:PORT` command.

Comment: And where is the EC2 instance created? Which subnet?

Comment: @MarkoE same private subnet where lambda and elasticache exists. It is something to do with connecting to TLS server.

Comment: I came across this fact, current memcached nodejs clients doesn't support TLS server.

Comment: According to [TLS support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76695170/15056828), how can I obtain certificate, if it is being natively managed by AWS (Serverless Elasticache).